# 12 Digit unique random number generation in Java

Tags: java

i was working on an application where we need to generate some unique number and practically there was no predefined restrictions so was using java UUD generator and was working fine.
Now we are given a new requirements to generate 12 digits unique random number.

Can any one point me some good way/algorithm to achieve this as i can not see any possibility in the UUID generated number.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Generate each digit by calling `random.nextInt`. For uniqueness, you can keep track of the random numbers you have used so far by keeping them in a set and checking if the set contains the number you generate each time.

```
public static long generateRandom(int length) {
    Random random = new Random();
    char[] digits = new char[length];
    digits[0] = (char) (random.nextInt(9) + '1');
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        digits[i] = (char) (random.nextInt(10) + '0');
    }
    return Long.parseLong(new String(digits));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(long)Math.random()*1000000000000L
```

But there are chances of collision

Why not use sequence? Starting from 100,000,000,000 to 999,999,999,999? keep a record of last generated number.

---

Edit: thanks to [bence olah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/562483/bence-olah), I fixed a creepy mistake

Comment: Not really good. The literal 1000000000000 of type int is out of range... (long) Math.random() * 1000000000000l is good

Comment: @Nishnat: keep record of last number indicating over head and you need to store the number at some place to other which i want to avoid

Comment: @umesh awasthi -- uniqueness can't be guaranteed by any other way. Ideally, you have only that many numbers. In long run, they will duplicate, if done otherwise.

Comment: Agree i have to settle down to a way to keep track of the last generated number

Answer (score 2):

Improved checked solution using StringBuilder():

```
public static long generateRandom() {
    Random random = new Random();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // first not 0 digit
    sb.append(random.nextInt(9) + 1);

    // rest of 11 digits
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        sb.append(random.nextInt(10));
    }

    return Long.valueOf(sb.toString()).longValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar requirement lately and came up with this:

```
import com.google.inject.Provider;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public final class SecureKeyProvider {

    private final SecureRandom rng;
    private final int entropyBytes;

    public SecureKeyProvider(int entropyBytes) {
        this.rng = new SecureRandom();
        this.entropyBytes = entropyBytes;
    }

    public String get() {

        /* SecureRandom documentation does not state if it's thread-safe,
         * therefore we do our own synchronization. see
         *
         * http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6498354
         */

        synchronized (this.rng) {
            final byte[] random = new byte[this.entropyBytes];
            rng.nextBytes(random);
            return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(random);
        }
    }

}
```

It uses the Base64 encoder from apache commons which I had in my project anyway. Maybe you want to replace it with something simple, but otherwise it does the job.

Comment: BTW: Unique *and* random seems a bit odd. I'd opt for choosing one of them, or dropping the 12 digits requirement and go with UUIDs as you already did.

Comment: agree and i have already placed a question.will think about random number only.

Answer (score 1):

```
Random random = new Random();
Math.round(random.nextFloat() * Math.pow(10,12))
```

Comment: yead, so it doesn't seem 'good' at all. There is no guarantee wrt uniqueness.

Comment: Right, in this case there is a chance for collision, one solution is to store the previous values and regenerate if collision happened. If the random generator doesn't have any state then there will always be a chance for collision.

Comment: BTW UUID is not 100% unique neither, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates .

Comment: agree its a good alternate and can do what u suggested to maintain uniqueness

Comment: This will NOT guarantee you 12 digits - only up to 12!

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.This is generating random number for 12 digits.you have to mention the ranges.

```
    package test;
import java.util.Random;
/** Generate random integers in a certain range. */
public final class RandomRange {
  public static final void main(String... aArgs){
    log("Generating random integers in the range 100000000000..999999999999.");
    long START = 100000000000l;
    long END = 999999999999l;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int idx = 1; idx <= 10; ++idx){
      showRandomInteger(START, END, random);
    }
    log("Done.");
  }

  private static void showRandomInteger(long aStart, long aEnd, Random aRandom){
    if ( aStart > aEnd ) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start cannot exceed End.");
    }
    //get the range, casting to long to avoid overflow problems
    long range = (long)aEnd - (long)aStart + 1;
    // compute a fraction of the range, 0 <= frac < range
    long randomNumber = (long)(range * aRandom.nextDouble());
    System.out.println(" fraction... "+randomNumber);
  }

  private static void log(String aMessage){
    System.out.println(aMessage);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting the UUIDs LSB and MSB halves as longs, and convert that to a number.

Comment: i can do that but not sure about the chances of collision in that case.i even tried that first but was not sure about the results so dropped the idea.

Comment: Your chances of collision will be slighthly higher than with a full UUID, since you have less data. You can check the RFC (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122) on that, and it seems that you have 60 bits from the timestamp, and one byte of version info. Outside that, it looks like pure randommness.

Answer (score 0):

The below is the best solution,I have written after tried multiple combination .
The below is the 12 digit unique Id....for every call & multiple threads also will return unique id .

Thanks
**CH.K M V Prasad***

```
private static int counter=0;
private static int oldMinute=-1;
private static int minIncr=0;


private static String repeatNumber(String repeatString ,int numberOftimes) {
    String returnStr="";
    for(int indexCounter=0;indexCounter<numberOftimes;indexCounter++) {
        returnStr+=repeatString;
    }
    return returnStr;
}

public synchronized static String getUniqueID() {

    System.out.println("curr Mill "+System.currentTimeMillis()+"D:"+(2020%1000)+"-"+(2021));
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    if(oldMinute==-1 || oldMinute< cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) ) {
        oldMinute=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        minIncr=0;
        counter=0;
    }else if(counter==99) {
        System.out.println("99 counter ");
        oldMinute=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+(++minIncr);
        counter=0;
    }
    String uId=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+""+cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+""+(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)%100)+""+oldMinute+""+cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
    String incrCounter=""+(++counter);
    int appendZeros=uId.length()+incrCounter.length();
    System.out.println("Uid="+uId+",incrCounter="+incrCounter+" , tolalZero="+appendZeros);
    return uId+repeatNumber("0", 12-appendZeros)+incrCounter;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
Random generator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
return generator.nextLong() % 1000000000000;
```

This will limit the result to 12 digits.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue (16 digits in my case) and didn't found a good solution so i created one [here](https://github.com/BrownTechnologies/random-unique-number-generator)

#### Idea

This utility works like clock, so you get unique random numbers per installation. we generate 16 digit integer value for example 2226015501234239

#### Implementation

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class App {
    private Set set = new HashSet<BigInteger>();
    private String flag = mostSignificantCounter();

    private String mostSignificantCounter() {
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        return new StringBuilder()
                .append((localDateTime.getYear() + "").substring(2))
                .append(localDateTime.getDayOfYear())
                .append(localDateTime.getHour())
                .append(localDateTime.getMinute())
                .append(localDateTime.getSecond())
                .toString();
    }

    private String leastSignificantCounter() {
        Random random = new Random(LocalDateTime.now().getNano());
        Integer rId = (1 + random.nextInt(10) * 10000) + random.nextInt(10000);
        return String.format("%05d", rId);
    }

    public BigInteger uniqueRandomBigInt() {
        String msc = mostSignificantCounter();
        BigInteger uniqueBigIntId = new BigInteger(msc + leastSignificantCounter());
        if (set.contains(uniqueBigIntId)) {
            return uniqueRandomBigInt();
        } else {
            if (!flag.equals(msc)) {
                set.clear();
                flag = msc;
            }
            set.add(uniqueBigIntId);
            return uniqueBigIntId;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Stress test

```
 @Test
    public void testApp() {
        Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        App app = new App();
        while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < (1000 * 60)) {
            BigInteger uniqueRandomBigInt = app.uniqueRandomBigInt();
            assertFalse(
                    testSet.contains(uniqueRandomBigInt),
                    "Failed to generate unique random ID, found duplicate -> " + uniqueRandomBigInt
            );
            testSet.add(uniqueRandomBigInt);
        }
        assertTrue(true);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would consider a simple hashing of System.nanoTime() assuming you don't mind the 1 out of 1 billion chance of hash collision.

Comment: no problem with such collision but what if  the method got hit in fraction of second so in that case there will be no diff in system time (assumption)

Comment: System.nanoTime() implies nanoseconds, or simply put 0.000000001 second, so I'm not sure if you'll find too many issues with the timestamps being the same (again possibly a 1 in 1 billion chance of collision).

@Waldheinz yes this is true, however the requirements seem slightly ambiguous to me since the original post refers to needing to generate a "unique id" and then later a "unique random id". So I suppose my solution is based upon the premise that it really just needs to be unique.

Comment: If two threads create 10000 IDs, one each millisecond, you have a collision chance of 1%. So if the application runs on more than one computer for a long time (and enterprise software certainly will), the IDs will NOT be unique.

Answer (score -2):

```
long number = 0l;
Random rand = new Random();
number = (rand.nextInt(1000000)+1000000000l) * (rand.nextInt(900)+100);
```