# Random Number generation Query

Tags: java, random

I used the following code to generate the random numbers:

```
long randNo = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
```

I have some situations where i found duplicates. Is it possible that it will generate same numbers?

Comment: ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655931/12-digit-unique-random-number-generation-in-java

Comment: You don't seem to understand what "random" means.

Comment: Ofcourse it is possible that it will generate the same numbers. Randomness and uniqueness are two totally different things.

Comment: Counter-question: if you execute this line of code 10001 times, what is the chance that it **doesn't** produce a duplicate value at least once?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. If you need to generate 10000 distinct random numbers from 0 to 9999. You can generate list of 10000 consecutive numbers and then call `Collections.shuffle` on it.

Answer (score 1):

With random numbers, all numbers in the range are equally likely.  This means if you get a number, the next value is just as likely to appear as it did the first time.

BTW: using round is not a great idea in you example as the numbers 1 to 9999 are equally likely but the numbers 0 and 10000 are half as likely as they only occur on a half rounded down or half rounded up.

A more efficient pattern is to use

```
Random rand = new Random();

// as needed
int num = rand.nextInt(10000); // will be [0, 10000)
```

If you need to generate unique numbers you can use Collections.shuffle

```
List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) nums.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(nums);
```

This will give you up to 10000 unique numbers in a random order.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to generate unique numbers in the above code? Thanks in advance